# New LAMP server, all links redirecting to localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, lamp

I've got a very frustrating issue with what should be a bespoke install of Ubuntu 12.04, the LAMP config provided in `apt-get install lamp-server^`, [and a web application called The Fascinator](https://sites.google.com/site/fascinatorhome/).

After installing those three things and making no changes to any of them, I can access the application through a public IP (http://lib-hf1.lib.sfu.ca:9997 for the curious), but the domain of every link within that page is changed to localhost, including links to images and CSS, so nothing loads correctly and all of the links are broken.

I've Googled around and found some people who appear to be having this issue with WP and Drupal, but nothing makes reference to a system-wide setting, and no one using the Fascinator seems to be having this issue. I have a faint memory that this might have something to do with `mod_rewrite`, but I'm pretty well stumped.

Comment: I've grepped around in the application's config a bit, and it seems that the localhost:9997 is in fact hardcoded -- I'm told I can somehow use mod_proxy to work around this? Sorry for groping in the dark, folks.